# testing if something is an empty list

Tags: clojure, is-empty, empty-list

Which way should I prefer to test if an object is an empty list in Clojure? Note that I want to test just this and not if it is empty as a sequence. If it is a "lazy entity" (`LazySeq`, `Iterate`, ...) I don't want it to get `realized?`.

Below I give some possible tests for `x`.

```clj
;0
(= clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList (class x))

;1
(and (list? x) (empty? x))

;2
(and (list? x) (zero? (count x)))

;3
(identical? () x)
```

Test 0 is a little low level and relies on "implementation details". My first version of it was `(instance? clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList x)`, which gives an `IllegalAccessError`. Why is that so? Shouldn't such a test be possible?

Tests 1 and 2 are higher level and more general, since `list?` checks if something implements `IPersistentList`. I guess they are slightly less efficient too. Notice that the order of the two sub-tests is important as we rely on short-circuiting.

Test 3 works under the assumption that every empty list is the same object. The tests I have done confirm this assumption but is it guaranteed to hold? Even if it is so, is it a good practice to rely on this fact?

All this may seem trivial but I was a bit puzzled not finding a completely straightforward solution (or even a built-in function) for such a simple task.

---

## update

Perhaps I did not formulate the question very well. In retrospect, I realized that what I wanted to test was if something is a non-lazy empty sequence. The most crucial requirement for my use case is that, **if it is a lazy sequence**, it does not get realized, i.e. **no thunk gets forced**.

Using the term "list" was a little confusing. After all what is a list? If it is something concrete like `PersistentList`, then it is non-lazy. If it is something abstract like `IPersistentList` (which is what `list?` tests and probably the correct answer), then non-laziness is not exactly guaranteed. It just so happens that Clojure's current lazy sequence types do not implement this interface.

So first of all I need a way to test if something is a lazy sequence. The best solution I can think of right now is to use `IPending` to test for laziness in general:

```
(def lazy? (partial instance? clojure.lang.IPending))
```

Although there are some lazy sequence types (e.g. chunked sequences like `Range` and `LongRange`) that do not implement `IPending`, it seems reasonable to expect that lazy sequences implement it in general. `LazySeq` does so and this is what really matters in my specific use case.

Now, relying on short-circuiting to prevent realization by `empty?` (and to prevent giving it an unacceptable argument), we have:

```
(defn empty-eager-seq? [x] (and (not (lazy? x)) (seq? x) (empty? x)))
```

Or, if we know we are dealing with sequences like in my case, we can use the less restrictive:

```
(defn empty-eager? [x] (and (not (lazy? x)) (empty? x)))
```

Of course we can write safe tests for more general types like:

```
(defn empty-eager-coll? [x] (and (not (lazy? x)) (coll? x) (empty? x)))
(defn empty-eager-seqable? [x] (and (not (lazy? x)) (seqable? x) (empty? x)))
```

That being said, the recommended test 1 also works for my case, thanks to short-circuiting and the fact that `LazySeq` does not implement `IPersistentList`. Given this and that the question's formulation was suboptimal, I will accept Lee's succinct answer and thank Alan Thompson for his time and for the helpful mini-discussion we had with an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 0 should be avoided since it relies on a class within `clojure.lang` that is not part of the public API for the package: From [the javadoc for clojure.lang](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/package-summary.html):

> The only class considered part of the public API is IFn. All other
>   classes should be considered implementation details.

Option 1 uses functions from the public API and avoids iterating the entire input sequence if it is non-empty

Option 2 iterates the entire input sequence to obtain the count which is potentially expensive.

Option 3 does not appear to be guaranteed and can be circumvented with reflection:

```
(identical? '() (.newInstance (first (.getDeclaredConstructors (class '()))) (into-array [{}])))

=> false
```

Given these I'd prefer option 1.

Comment: Notice that in option 2, due to short-circuiting, the problem you mentioned will appear only if the tested object is an `IPersistentList` and is not a `Counted`, because for a `Counted` `count` takes constant time. But all classes that currently implement `IPersistentList` (i.e. `PersistentList` and `PersistentQueue`) also implement `Counted`. Anyway I still prefer the simplicity of option 1...

Answer (score 1):

Just use choice (1):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(defn empty-list? [arg] (and (list? arg)
                          (not (seq arg))))
(dotest
  (isnt (empty-list? (range)))
  (isnt (empty-list? [1 2 3]))
  (isnt (empty-list? (list 1 2 3)))

  (is (empty-list? (list)))
  (isnt (empty-list? []))
  (isnt (empty-list? {}))
  (isnt (empty-list? #{})))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

Ran 2 tests containing 7 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

As you can see by the first test with `(range)`, the infinite lazy seq didn't get realized by `empty?`.

---

**Update**

Choice 0 depends on implementation details (unlikely to change, but why bother?).  Also, it is noisier to read.

Choice 2 will blow up for infinite lazy seq's.

Choice 3 is not guaranteed to work.  You could have more than one list with zero elements.

---

**Update #2**

OK, you are correct re (2).  We get:

```
(type (range)) => clojure.lang.Iterate
```

Notice that ***it is not a Lazy-Seq*** as both you and I expected.

So you are relying on a (non-obvious) detail to prevent getting to `count`, which will blow up for an infinite lazy seq.  Too subtle for my taste.  My motto:  Keep it ***as obvious as possible***

Re choice (3), again it relies on the implementation detail of (the current release of) Clojure.  I could almost make it fail except that `clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList` is a package-protected inner class, so I would have to really try hard (subvert Java inheritance) to make a duplicate instance of the class, which would then fail.

However, I can come close:

```
(defn el3? [arg] (identical? () arg))

(dotest
  (spyx (type (range)))
  (isnt (el3? (range)))
  (isnt (el3? [1 3 3]))
  (isnt (el3? (list 1 3 3)))

  (is (el3? (list)))
  (isnt (el3? []))
  (isnt (el3? {}))
  (isnt (el3? #{}))

  (is (el3? ()))
  (is (el3? '()))
  (is (el3? (list)))
  (is (el3? (spyxx (rest [1]))))

  (let [jull (LinkedList.)]
    (spyx jull)
    (spyx (type jull))
    (spyx (el3? jull))) ; ***** contrived, but it fails *****
```

with result

```
jull => ()
(type jull) => java.util.LinkedList
(el3? jull) => false
```

So, I again make a plea to keep it obvious and simple.

---

> There are two ways of constructing a software design. One way is to
>   make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies. And the
>   other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious
>   deficiencies.
>       ---C.A.R. Hoare

Comment: Thanks. How do you justify this choice? Do you have any answer to the other "sub-questions" too?

Comment: (The only option whose correctness I doubt is number 3. For the rest I know they work.)

Comment: Choice 2 will not blow up, because of short-circuiting (`list?` will fail for a `LazySeq`). Can you provide an example of choice 3 not working? Or maybe a link to documentation/implementation? In every way I have produced empty lists, they were all `identical?`. Also can you explain why `instance?` doesn't work in choice 0?

Comment: BUT in exactly the same detail we rely in choice 1 to prevent realization (not full, just the first `Cons`) by `empty?`. Lots of thanks for the work you've done for choice 3, I'll read it again tomorrow with a clear mind but it looks convincing...

Comment: As for choice 0: The "noisy to read" argument isn't very strong, since wrapping the test in an `empty-list?` function means we write it only once. Also couldn't its concreteness be more desirable in some cases? E.g. if someone creates a new lazy sequence type that also implements `IPersistentList`, choices 1 and 2 would realize such a sequence.

Comment: Perhaps an ideal solution would involve a high-level way to check if something is a "non-lazy list" (thus defining this concept), which doesn't seem to exist. Could we check if it implements `IPending` for that purpose?

Comment: (I've just made up a motto of my own: "Achieving simplicity can be complicated. Obviousness can be deceptive.")